# Product barcode with expiration date

Tags: sql, sql-server, barcode

For now I want to make an inventory system that tracks the expiration date of a product

**My question is how to track a single product that has a single `barcode number` but have different expiration date**

Example

| `ProductName` | `Barcode` | `ExpirationDate` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oreo | 1231232123 | june 10, 2021 |
| Oreo | 1231232123 | july 13, 2021 |

**Or is it possible to track `ExpirationDate` using barcode as reference?**

Comment: These are individual items of the same product, right? You probably need an ID field for your table, so you can uniquely identify each item. An auto increment field ought to be fine. Is that what you're asking? It's not very clear what you mean by "track" exactly

Comment: @ADyson yes these are individual items, and it had ```ProductID``` in the database, but when the cashier scan the barcode, how to identify that barcode with the equivalent ```ExpirationDate```.

Comment: because the 2 items have the same barcode, and only the barcode is swiped in the cashier it doesn't scan the ```ExpirationDate```.

Comment: If all you have is the barcode shown above, you can't differentiate them. Are you sure there's nothing in the scanned barcode on the packet which identifies the unique item of stock as well as the product type? I don't know much about barcodes but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to do that.

Comment: @ADyson The Example Oreo which i bought at different time and store have same ```barcode``` but have different ```ExpirationDate```.

Comment: @ADyson no wonder i haven't heard about POS and inventory system that notifies the client if there is a product that about to expire that haven't sold yet hahaha

Comment: Some barcode formats like GTIN have an optional expiration data segment. Same product with different expiration will have the same beggining and differ in the expiration segment. Your barcode format does no seem to have that information.

Comment: @user6788933 yes sir my example is based on what i bought in 2 different stores recently, just wondering f i had to make a system that sends to the client that this product is about to expire, how can i differentiate this product from another product that has the same barcode.

Comment: I wonder if you need to do some more systematic research into barcodes than just buying a few items from a store...

Comment: @ADyson yes sir ill do it, just posting it in here incase someone had some idea about it.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for commenting sir, i might close this post because my friend told me that its someone's duty in the warehouse of the store to do FIFO of the products and i should put the product with the closest Exp. Date in the invoice.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to track the specific items, then that's probably a reasonable approach. It's good that you have some information about what the industry does in reality.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are the one making the system. A possible solution is first have the products table with names and unique barcode nos and etc.

Then you need another table to store the expiry date of each product and here you have the unique ID per entry which links it to the product and maybe has another barcode that identifies the entry.

This table should be probably populated when you bringing stock in (Purchase).

Then your product can have two barcodes,one for expiry entry and one for the product itself. So when you need to identify the product by expiry date scan the expiry date barcode.

Then you just need to figure out how to deal with quantity per product per expiry date. Probably add it to the same expiry table

Comment: Though reading through the comments. I would first check all possible barcode options and see which one you can take advantage off to simplify your system. Maybe it is easier to use QR codes to avoid double barcodes

Comment: its a POS that uses Barcode Scanner to scan data sir, now i wonder if i want to make a system that notify the client that this product is about to expire and how can i differentiate from other products with the same barcode.

Comment: As i mentioned, before building the system do some research into barcodes. You can scan the QR code with a barcode scanner, but they are usually more expensive. So in the QR code you can store more information than a normal barcode. In which case when selling the product you can scan the QR code and the system can figure out if the product is about to expiry based on the expiration date encoded in the QR code. This way you dont need to scan two barcodes

Answer (score -1):

The better way is by Including a Primary Key ID column in your table for the Products. Then you can track each item.

Comment: yes these are individual items, and it had ```ProductID``` in the database, but when the cashier scan the barcode, how to identify that barcode with the equivalent ```ExpirationDate```. Because the 2 items have the same barcode, and only the barcode is swiped in the cashier it doesn't scan the ```ExpirationDate```.

Answer (score -1):

I probably add some like IDs and thanks this u can track it.

Comment: yes these are individual items, and it had ```ProductID``` in the database, but when the cashier scan the barcode, how to identify that barcode with the equivalent ```ExpirationDate```. Because the 2 items have the same barcode, and only the barcode is swiped in the cashier it doesn't scan the ```ExpirationDate```.

Comment: Ah, now I completely understand. I am not sure, if you can track each one with different expiration date. You have only one option (i think)- show the closest exp. day or 3  closest or whatever you want with counts - this is what i will made if i was you

Comment: yes sir i will assume that, but what if the store displays a product with different Exp.date and he pick the one with farther exp. date and your system pick the closest exp.date, that will affect with the inventory, right?

Comment: Yep, u probably must physical look at the item exp. date..
But this solution is only if you want only one barcode. As someone wrote, with 2 barcodes od QR codes u can track it better with exp date. Or some RFID tags.